# Is PDF unique for a random variable $X$ in given probability space?

Tags: probability

A random variable $X$ is a measurable function from a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ to the reals:

$X: \Omega \to (-\infty, \infty)$

such that for every Borel set $B$,

$X^{-1}(B)=\{\omega \in \Omega:X(\omega) \in B\} \in \mathcal{F}$

shorthand notation: $\{X \in B\}=\{\omega \in \Omega:X(\omega) \in B\}$

in other words, the fact that value of $X$ belongs to a given Borel has to be an event (has to belong to the set of events $\mathcal{F}$).

Is the probability density function unique for every random variable $X$ in the probabilty space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$?

I think the answer is yes, because $\mathbb{P(}{a \le X \le b})$ is defined by the probability function $\mathbb{P}$.

$a \le X \le b$ is an event belonging to $\mathcal{F}$, and $\mathbb{P}$ defines what are probabilities of events in $\mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Let it be that $f,g:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ are Borel-measurable functions with: $$\lambda\{x\in\mathbb R\mid f(x)\neq g(x)\}=0$$

where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

If $f$ serves as PDF for random variable $X$, then so does $g$.

This because for each Borel-measurable set $A$: $$\mathbb P(X\in A)=\int_Afd\lambda=\int_Agd\lambda$$

Comment: Consider the subset of real-valued RVs which place probability one on some contiguous interval. Can we *define* the pdf to be, say, the right continuous version with support subintervals required to have form $[a,b)$ in its piecewise definition? This should make such a pdf unique as we then can't arbitrarily move a countable number of points. E.g. it *forces* uniform $X$ to have pdf $f_X(x)=1$ on $0\leq x<1$.

Comment: @jdods There are indeed situations in which some extra condition on the pdf is only satisfied by one (so a unique) pdf. And in lots of cases these are the pdf's that are used in practice. But a pdf already has a general definition and *redefining* it has no added value. Usually we just pick one out that suits well. In most cases one that is continuous (or - if that is not possible - has a finite/small number of discontinuity points).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, not all random variables have a pdf. But even if they have, the answer is no, the densities are not uniquely determined by the distribution. For example $X \sim U(0,1)$ and $Y\sim U[0,1]$ have the same distribution but different pdf's. It is possible to change the pdf in countable many points and to keep the cdf the same.

However, the cdf *uniquely determines the probability law* $\mathbb P_X$ of the random variable $X$, that is the probability $$P(X\in B), \quad B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$$ The changes that I mentioned above are in sets of $\mathbb P_X$-measure zero and so do not affect these probabilities.

Comment: The point is that there are many PDFs, but the value of integral $\int_a^b f_x(x) dx$ is equal for all of them?

Comment: Yes exactly, (assuming a pdf exists).

Comment: Is this statement true: If two (absolutely continuous) RVs have the same distribution, then their pdf's are equal almost everywhere?

Comment: @JimmyR. You said "For example $X \sim U(0,1)$ and $Y\sim U[0,1]$ have the same distribution but different pdf's. now if pdf of  $X \sim U(0,1)$ is $f1$ then we cant say it also be a pdf of $Y\sim U[0,1]$?